# Is there a way to make a custom border in CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was given this word document as a reference for what they want made into a ReactJS app (they didn't specify the language but that's ultimately what ended up being the thing I both knew and was most convenient). I am having no trouble making everything they asked for except for this one specific thing which is a border of a specific style.

This image is an example of the border they're looking for.

[image]

I can figure out how to make a dotted border and a dashed one but not one going between one and the other. Here's my CSS code so far:

```css
.instructions {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's what it looks like when run:

[image]

Is there any way to make custom borders?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make custom borders with images. See this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image-repeat

Comment: @Azu so would I just get an image of a hyphen and a period and then use that as a border? I can't seem to make that work but it's partially because I don't know what everything does. I'm not the most experienced CSS user to bear with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SVG elements have the [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) property, which can be used to make custom borders like that (in an svg).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="4px" stroke-dasharray="16 2 2 2" />
</svg>
```

in the above example all the sizes are hard coded, but they don't need to be. if you write an svg like this

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="4px" stroke-dasharray="16 2 2 2" />
</svg>
```

you can then use it as a background image in your html, and it will scale to fill whatever container you put it in.

to use it as a background image you can you can just save the svg file somewhere and reference it from your css the same way you would with any other image, or you can turn the svg into a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) ([this tool](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) is useful for that).

```css
.demo_box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
.custom_svg_border {
  /* this border won't actually take up any space since it's a background image, so add some extra padding to account for that */
  padding: 2px;
  /* background-image: url("foo/bar/custom_border.svg"); */
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Crect x='0%25' y='0%25' width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='transparent' stroke='black' stroke-width='4px' stroke-dasharray='16 2 2 2' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_svg_border demo_box">
  hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing i got for you is this

```css
     .instructions {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 35px;
        top: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightblue;
        border: dashed 3px black;
      }
      .instructions::after {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: -3px;
        top: -3px;
        position: absolute;
        border: dotted 3px black;
      }
```

```html
<div class="instructions">content</div>
```

Note that all three values `border-width`, `top`,and `left` need to be the same. for example if your `border-width` is 5px your `top` and `left` need to be set at -5px

Comment: Thank you for the idea but unfortunately this didn't work. It just creates a border with two dashes instead of just one.

Comment: try messing around with the `top` `left` and the border witdth styles. i did that for around 30 minutes to get this one right!. note that all three values need to be the same. for example if your border width is 5px your `top` and `left` need to be set at -5px.

Comment: or use the same numbers as i do

Answer (score -2):

It's impossible to do it with just `css` and, if possible, it will also be very hard to achieve with `javascript`.

Notice that if you get close, text with  hypehns and dots won't be aligned vertically... It won't be aligned also if you use underscore.

Using an image as border is the way to go as they have already told you.

Asuming you still want to try this is what I would do as a start... good luck transforming the example with `javascript`, if you can you'll have quite a nice sucesfull career ahead:

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.border-container {
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:200px; 
  margin:0 auto;
}
.border-container:after {
  content:'_ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ .';
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  display:blocK;
  position:absolute;
  top:-18px;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.border-container:before {
  content:'_ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ .';
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  display:blocK;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.border-left {
  overflow: hidden;
    display: blocK;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 200px;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.border-right {
  overflow: hidden;
    display: blocK;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 200px;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-container">
  <div class="border-left">
  _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ .
  </div> 
   <div class="border-right">
  _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ . _ .
  </div> 
 
</div>
```

Comment: I thought it would  be this hard so thank you for putting in the effort to try and make things work. Also loved the comment about the nice successful career ahead that gave me a hearty chuckle.